# JS Class Abstraction

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have been trying to create an abstract class that can modify variables from the inheriting class, but i am facing an issue when i set an empty variable in the inheriting class, the abstract class won't set it ?

**this example DO NOT WORK**

```js
class Abc {
  constructor() {
    this.id = "x";
  }
}
class Test extends Abc {
  id;
}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test)
```

**this example DO WORK**

```js
class Abc {
  constructor() {
    this.id = "x";
  }
}
class Test extends Abc {
}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test)
```

Comment: If you want a child class instance to have an undefined ID, change `id;` to `id = undefined;`, is that what you want?

Comment: JS does not support abstract classes...

Comment: `id;` is not valid as part of an ES6 class. Are you using some experimental syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "abstract class"? One can easily instantiate a `new Abc`.

Comment: When making a question instead of saying 'this does work' and 'this doesn't work', you should explain what the code *does* , what you *want* it to do and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise them your id with undefined but also set it an optional field in constructor in case you want to set in when creating instance.

You can't have abstract classes in JS but you can add a simple validation to prevent direct instantiations:

```
class AbstractClass {
  constructor(id = undefined) {
    if (new.target.name === AbstractClass.name) {
      throw new Error("Can not create instance of Abstract class");
    }
    this.id = id;
  }
}

class DerivedClass extends AbstractClass {}

const disallowed = new AbstractClass(); // throws error 
const allowed = new DerivedClass(1); // will work fine
```

Comment: You could even omit that `constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }`, the default constructor does the same